# Регулярные выражения для поиска js файлов на node js

Tags: регулярные-выражения, node.js

Вот код, который находит в файле все ссылки на `js` скрипт и смотрит, если есть этот скрипт в папке, то ничего не нужно делать, а если нету, то заменить на ссылку. Но у меня почему-то меняются строки не так, как нужно. Помогите!

```
var fs = require('fs');
var fail = fs.readFileSync("test.html", {encoding:'utf-8'});
var temp = require('stream');
var path = require('path');

var a ="'" ;
var http = /((http\:\/\/)?(\w+\.)+\w+(\/[^\s]+)?(.js))/;
var adr =  /(\w+(\/[^\s]+)?(.js))/g;


var i=0;
while(adr.exec(fail)){
    temp=fail.match(adr)[i];
    console.log(temp);
    if (fs.existsSync(path.join(temp))) {console.log("Yraaa"); } else {fail =    fail.replace(adr, 'httptemp')}
    console.log(adr.lastIndex);
    i++;

}
```

**Обновление**

Вот лог

```
> dima@vlzkonopatov-PK ~/WebstormProjects/openF $ nodejs zq

script1.js
91
script111.js
129
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <script src="httptemp"></script>
    <script src="script11.js"></script>
    <script src="httptemp"></script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Вот файл

```
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <script src="script1.js"></script>
    <script src="script11.js"></script>
    <script src="script111.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Файл html находится в папке со скриптом. `script1.js` в папке нет как и `script11.js` `script11.js`
Но когда запускаю программу он меняет

```
 <script src="script1.js"></script> на <script src="httptemp">
 <script src="script11.js"></script> не трогает вообще
 <script src="script111.js"></script> на <script src="httptemp">
```

Comment: хотелось бы пример того, что меняется не так как нужно

Comment: Файл html находится в папке со скриптом. script1.js в папке нет как и script11.js script11.js 
Но когда запускаю программу он меняет  
 <script src="script1.js"></script> на <script src="httptemp">
 <script src="script11.js"></script> не трогает вообще
 <script src="script111.js"></script> на <script src="httptemp">

Answer (score 1):

Ответ из вопроса:

---

Разобрался я и вот решение Если кому-то будет нужно

```
var fs = require('fs');
var fail = fs.readFileSync("test.html", {encoding:'utf-8'});
//var http = /((http\:\/\/)?(\w+\.)+\w+(\/[^\s]+)?(.js))/;
var adr =  /((\w+(\/[^\s]+)?(\.js))|(\w+(\/[^\s]+)?(\.css))|(((http\:\/\/)|((https\:\/\/)))?(\w+\.)+\w+(\/[^\s]+)?(.js)))/g;

fail.replace(adr, function(a) {return fs.existsSync(a) ? "www. ........"+a : a  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы работать с html, лучше использовать html-парсер, вместо регулярных выражений, например, [cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio) предоставляет (подмножество) jQuery интерфейса, который работает на сервере.